scipy fsolve can't solve equation with logarithm
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x):
    return [x[0] * 0.00096 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.00096/x[2]) - 1.2505,
            x[0] * 0.00301 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.00301/x[2]) - 1.2829,
            x[0] * 0.000077 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.000077/x[2]) - 1.1789,]

root = fsolve(func, [66, 1, 43])

So the problem is that fsolve can't find solution for my equations system. When I run the code I get the following error:
<ipython-input-19-7ecad596ddb5>:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  return [x[0] * 0.00096 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.00096/x[2]) - 1.2505,
<ipython-input-19-7ecad596ddb5>:3: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  x[0] * 0.00301 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.00301/x[2]) - 1.2829,
<ipython-input-19-7ecad596ddb5>:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  x[0] * 0.000077 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.000077/x[2]) - 1.1789,]

I'm clueless about what to do. What may be the problem?
Edit: I forgot to mention that variables must be non-zero and positive  with x[1] between 1 and 2 and x[2] must be several negative powers of 10.

Most likely x[2] is either 0 or negative at some point in the optimizers evaluation sequence. You need to defend your function against that possibility. Try a starting guess [1,1,40] which is nearer to the answer. I get a sloppy fit {-0.009,-1E-04, 35.74}.

x[2] is going negative. Do you know that there is a root?

Add a print(x) at the start of the function to see what values it's geting.

@MartinBrown yeah I thought about it too. However, in complex analysis as far as I know log works for negative numbers just fine. Does any external python module handle negatives in logs like sqrt function in math module does?

@jared supposed to be...

@hpaulj at some point negatives emerge

fsolve only works with real numbers and np.log only works with negative real numbers when you pass in complex numbers.

In my tests x[2] quickly becomes -2.53.  The np.log produces this warning, and a nan value.  math.log doesn't like this any better, raising a domain error.  Providing a complex start array, raises an error when fsolve tries to cast the complex result to float.

@jared so how should I fix program? Btw I added a P.S. saying that there are several constrains on searched variables

" x[2] must be several negative powers of 10" Can you clarify this point? Are you saying that x[2] must be 10^-1, 10^-2, and it cannot be any of the numbers in between? Are you saying that it must be 10^1, 10^2, and none of the numbers in between, since it's in the denominator?

You can use optimize.minimize, which allows you to put bounds and other constraints on the variables, then minimize a norm of the residuals. The bounds should be respected in each iteration.

I've tested different ways of finding the root in scipy (real and complex) and have also tried mpmath.findroot (which can find complex roots), but wasn't able to get a root that way either. Part of it could be a bad guess.

It is 3 equations and 3 unknowns. I threw it at a fairly robust fitter and got a whole range  of possible of answers which roughly amount to x[2] ~ 30-50 x[1]/9 =  x[0] ~= -1e-4. There are no real solutions for constraining 1< x[1] < 2. OP might try Maxima solve equations which will automatically switch into complex notation when things get tricky. scipy fsolve was doing it's best but it was given a very poor starting guess (and constraints which make any real solution completely impossible).

You can solve it analytically (proof at the bottom).
I don't agree that all values are positive, though. If you use
root = fsolve(func, [-1, 1, 1e-23])

then you will get the correct root (which I believe to be unique in real numbers).
1. Via exact solution
The proof and notation are given at the bottom of the post. This is soluble in this instance because the only non-linear bit is actually repeated between equations and hence can be subtracted away, leaving simultaneous linear equations. This is a problem-specific bit of luck.
import math

a, b, c, d, e = 0.00096, 0.00301, 0.000077, 0.0259, 0.00096
f, g, h = 1.2505, 1.2829, 1.1789

det = d * ( ( a - c ) * math.log( b /c ) - ( b - c ) * math.log( a / c ) )
y = ( ( g - h ) * ( a - c ) - ( f - h ) * ( b - c ) ) / det
x = ( g - h  - d * math.log( b / c ) * y ) / ( b - c )
logz = ( a * x + d * math.log( a ) * y - f ) / ( d * y )
z = math.exp( logz )

print( "x, y, z = ", x, y, z )

print( "Check:" )
print( 0.00096  * x + 0.0259 * y * math.log( 0.00096  / z ) - 1.2505 )
print( 0.00301  * x + 0.0259 * y * math.log( 0.00301  / z ) - 1.2829 )
print( 0.000077 * x + 0.0259 * y * math.log( 0.000077 / z ) - 1.1789 )

Result:
x, y, z =  -0.017395040681110335 1.095890481308894 7.050533107244206e-23
Check:
0.0
0.0
0.0

2. Using a better guess in the original code
This is a useful check, but it really depends on the hindsight acquired from method 1!
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def func(x):
    return [x[0] * 0.00096 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.00096/x[2]) - 1.2505,
            x[0] * 0.00301 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.00301/x[2]) - 1.2829,
            x[0] * 0.000077 + x[1]*0.0259*np.log(0.000077/x[2]) - 1.1789,]
root = fsolve(func, [-1, 1, 1e-23])
print( root )

Output:
[-1.73950407e-02  1.09589048e+00  7.05053311e-23]

3. Solving for a transformed variable
This is included because it might be a help in future problems involving logarithms.
The issues with this system are the possibility of the argument to the logarithm going negative and the large range of magnitudes in the solution. Both issues may be circumvented by solving for x, y, log(z) first. (You just have to remember to reverse the logarithm at the end!) The system is now much less fussy about the initial guess.
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def func(x):
    return [x[0] * 0.00096 + x[1]*0.0259*( math.log(0.00096 ) - x[2] ) - 1.2505,
            x[0] * 0.00301 + x[1]*0.0259*( math.log(0.00301 ) - x[2] ) - 1.2829,
            x[0] * 0.000077 + x[1]*0.0259*(math.log(0.000077) - x[2] ) - 1.1789,]
root = fsolve(func,[1,1,1])
x, y, z = root[0], root[1], math.exp( root[2] )
print( "x, y, z = ", x, y, z )

Output:
x, y, z =  -0.017395040681282763 1.0958904813088965 7.050533107244006e-23

Proof of Exact Result


That looks to me like the true solution supported by the algebra. Numerical solvers (even robust ones) quickly get lost in the pseudo minimum in the region of x[2] ~ 40 and then spend a lot of time refining a not quite right solution that is  just too far away from the true solution of x[2] ~ 10^-23 to ever stand a chance of finding it. A good analytical guesstimate makes a lot of difference to getting the right answer.

Agreed. Also, with a little bit of the benefit of hindsight, numerical solvers might find it easier to solve first for x, y and log(z) first, rather than x, y, z. It would quietly circumvent the issue of putting anything negative inside a logarithm and also deal with extreme difference in magnitude between the values.

@lastchance I just tested that and it works well.

Ah, thanks for that. A useful thing to remember for future solver exercises. What with the need for either judicious rearrangements or a good initial guess, some of these library routines aren't quite as hands-off, black-box tools as they are sometime portrayed.

They can be used as black boxes for many problems, but even the simplest of problems can stump them. But knowing these tricks is useful. I was originally thinking that some transformation of the problem would make this problem easier to solve, but I think your suggestion with the log term is simplest. Consider adding that option to your answer?

Thanks, @Jared. It would be useful to remember it (and justify the choice). I have added it to my post as the third method.
